# My CoreData storing is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Im starting in iPhone programming and Im making my first CoreData app by myself, In the data Im storing is a color, and two strings but right now im only reading one string and the color, but this is not working, heres my code so you can help me, thanks.

Method for saving the info:

```
+(void)insertNewAccountCard:(NSString *) title
                withcontent:(NSString *) content
                  withcolor:(NSData *) color{
    [MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        Note *note = [Note MR_createEntity];
        note.titulo = title;
        note.content = content;
        note.color = color;

        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Accounts:%d", [CoreDataBase numberofNotes]);
    }];
}
+(NSInteger) numberofNotes{

    return [Note MR_countOfEntities];
}
```

In my entity class (Note) `color` is NSData obviously.

Then I store the info:

```
- (IBAction)DoneAction:(id)sender {
    //[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
    [CoreDataBase insertNewAccountCard:self.titleTextfield.text withcontent:nil withcolor:data];
}
- (IBAction)gray:(id)sender {
    color = [UIColor grayColor];
    NSLog(@"%@", color);
}
```

And then when I read it:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [CoreDataBase numberofNotes];

}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NotesCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Note *notes = self.allNotes[indexPath.row];
    UIColor *color = (UIColor *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:notes.color];
    cell.noteView.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.titleCellLabel.text = notes.titulo;

    return cell;
}
```

So the collection view appears to be totally empty, but if I put an UIColor to the cell view background I can see that the count of the number of notes is actually working but without the text and the view color that I select, so whats wrong? I hope you can help me.

Comment: You're only saving one string (`titulo`) and you're also only reading one (the same), so it's not clear what problem you're having. In what way is this not working?

Comment: Hi, Im also saving a color transformed into a NSData, the problem is when I try to load the CoreData info into my CollectionView It loads the number of cells but not the content (view background color and title label). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever commit the changes? See under "Saving Changes" in:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html